# R - sum #occurrences of a string for each unique person

Tags: r

I want to transform this

```
     Person    Error_Type
[1,]  Name_1      Type_A
[2,]  Name_2      Type_B
[3,]  Name_1      Type_A
[4,]  Name_3      Type_C
[5,]  Name_2      Type_C
[6,]  Name_1      Type_B
```

Into this:

```
      Person     Type_A     Type_B    Type_C
[1,]  Name_1       2          1          -     
[2,]  Name_2       -          1          1   
[3,]  Name_3       -          0          1
```

Both `Names_` and `Type_` are strings

Thanks!

Comment: So what code have you tried so far?

Comment: First thanks for your reply @Zach , I'm really just starting with R. 
I know that I can use unique(db$Person) to get all unique values in the person's column, I'm not sure how to sum unique(db$Error_Type) occurrences by unique(db$Person)

Comment: Do note: your post shows a matrix and not a data frame. You cannot have different data types in a matrix, only one type across all elements. Prior to aggregation, convert to dataframe (a list of equal length atomic vectors) which can have heterogeneous types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @thelatemail pointed out for the example given, `table` gives almost exactly what the OP requested in one function call.

```
df <- data.frame(Person = c("Name_1","Name_2","Name_1","Name_3","Name_2","Name_1"),
Error_Type = c("Type_A","Type_B","Type_A","Type_C","Type_C","Type_B"),
stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

table(df)
        Error_Type
Person   Type_A Type_B Type_C
  Name_1      2      1      0
  Name_2      0      1      1
  Name_3      0      0      1
```

However, the OP has stated that the actual data is a bit more complex than the given example. Below is a base R solution that should work on a more general level.

```
MakeDf <- function(myDf) {
    myCols <- unique(myDf$Error_Type)
    z <- split(myDf, myDf$Person)
    lenR <- length(z)
    newDf <- data.frame(matrix(rep(0, lenR*length(myCols)), nrow = lenR))
    colnames(newDf) <- myCols; rownames(newDf) <- names(z)
    for (i in 1:lenR) {
        t <- rle(z[[i]]$Error_Type)
        newDf[i, t$values] <- t$lengths
    }
    newDf
}

MakeDf(df)
       Type_A Type_B Type_C
Name_1      2      1      0
Name_2      0      1      1
Name_3      0      0      1
```

This function takes advantage of [split](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/split.html) and [rle](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/rle.html) (very similar to [table](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/table.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Try this... (myMat is the matrix described above)

```
myMat <- data.frame(myMat)
aggregate(myMat, by = list(myMat$Error_Type), FUN = length)
```

The function will aggregate the first argument by the function specified, by the things listed in "by" argument.

Comment: `aggregate(dat["Error_Type"], dat, FUN = length)` would be simpler if you want this format. Excluding the obvious `table(dat)` to get a result similar to what OP requested.

Comment: @thelatemail Entirely accurate; I'm merely a creature of habit, and this was the first way I learned to aggregate data. I'm reading up on `table()` as we speak, as it looks like it could save me some keystrokes going forward.

Comment: @honeyBunchesOfFloats @thelatemail

On my actual database I have other columns, this is almost working but not quite.
The closest I could get from what I want was this code: 

`aggregate(db$Person, by = list(db$Person,db$Error_Type), FUN = length)`

Which gives me a table with header 'Group.1', 'Group.2' and 'x'

Containing:
'Group.1' : Name the person
'Group.2': Type of error
'x': Total number of that occurrences.

What I want as headers would be 'Person', 'Error Type A', 'Error Type B',...  and only row for each person

Comment: Perhaps try looking at the melt function in the reshape package.